# Generalizing INPUT fields cross-browser

Tags: css, cross-browser

Is there a CSS (non-javascript) way to make input fields (text/textarea/password) shown the same way cross-browsers (from IE7+ and all other common browsers (safari, chrome, firefox)) ?

Comment: Behavior and rendering of input fields is controlled by the browser itself. If you want something that is in every browser the same you will need to implement your own input fields.

Comment: You probably shouldn't care. Users are used to their form elements looking a certain way on their platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some great code you should check out. It has a polyfill for older browsers, but it will make all of your form fields look pretty close. You can use just the CSS portion and it is still pretty awesome. It's called [Formalize](http://formalize.me/). It is not identical in every browser but it's pretty close.

If you are worried about pixel perfect similarity you will have to use a javascript like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) or [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) since select fields are usually the elements that vary the most between browsers. You could also take a look at [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). They already have a lot of work done for you. Good luck!